# Agregar opacidad en Mapas WMS generados con gvNIX

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

Siguiendo el documento de referencia de gvNIX existe un componente geo para el **Control de opacidad de capas** que se agrega incluyendo a la vista show.jspx del mapa el siguiente tag

```
        <geo:toc-toolbar id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_toc_toolbar"
            z="user-managed">
            <tool:opacity id="opacity_slider" z="user-managed" />
        </geo:toc-toolbar>
```

dentro de la barra de herramientas toc-toolbar.
A mi mapa base agregue dos capas WMS más que me gustaria que tambien cuenten con ese componente. Me gustaria saber si es posible o si estoy realizando la inclusion de alguna manera erronea, mi codigo es el siguiente.

```
<geo:toc id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_toc"
        z="+MeANZ7lrQ3PHfF88iYJKjjbAyE=">

        <geo:toc-toolbar id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_toc_toolbar"
            z="user-managed">
            <tool:opacity id="opacity_slider" z="user-managed" />
        </geo:toc-toolbar>

        <layer:tile allowDisable="false"
            id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_default_layer"
            url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?bar"
            z="sKKvxQpO3LQFui93VegdYDtJKSE=" />

        <layer:entity filterType="auto" id="l_org_cite_pese_dominio_Estacion"
            path="/estacions" pk="id" selection="true"
            z="fXDq1x3/hgf9UGoxlV2AHiUbFD0=">

            <layer:entity-field field="ubicacion" icon="glyphicon-map-marker"
                iconLibrary="glyphicon"
                id="l_org_cite_pese_dominio_Estacion_ubicacion"
                labelingProperty="codPese" markerColor="darkred" showInfo="true"
                z="0oVQrurrzX/dVZ4cdNJ51XLWsoo=" />

        </layer:entity>

        <layer:wms format="image/png" 
            id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_limitaciones"
            layers="PesePy:Limites_PY" transparent="true"
            url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PesePy/wms?" version="1.1.0"
            z="k8i1DhIaSY4wyNWXZ8HPQUpMR8E=" />

        <layer:wms format="image/png"
            id="ps_org_cite_pese_web_Mapa_Departamentos"
            layers="PesePy:dptos_py" transparent="true"
            url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PesePy/wms?" version="1.1.0"
            z="S9Y1+dZNhp6mNujRQqjTTZMJhFY=" />
    </geo:toc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es un bug que está corregido en la versión final.

Prueba los siguiente:

1. edita el fichero [leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/webapp/scripts/leaflet/leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js) de tu proyecto.
2. Copia desde la línea [3842](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/webapp/scripts/leaflet/leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js#L3842) a la [3863](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/webapp/scripts/leaflet/leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js#L3863) o lo que es lo mismo, las funciones `fnSetOpacity` y `fnGetOpacity`.
3. Pégalas antes de la línea [3755](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/webapp/scripts/leaflet/leaflet.ext.gvnix.map.js#L3755) o lo que es lo mismo, dentro del *prototype* del objeto de la capa wms.

A partir de ese momento, al seleccionar en el TOC las capas WMS se debería activar el control de opacidad.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto! Muchisimas gracias una vez mas..

Comment: Me alegro. De nada ;-)